# How to generate a Java method reference using Groovy for testing purposes

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, method-reference

I'm using `Groovy` with `JUnit` to test my `Java` code.

I need to test a method `foo()` which takes in a `java.util.function.Function`

```
public void foo(Function<Foo,Bar> func){
    return null; 
}
```

In my normal code I call `foo` by passing in a method reference of a method `bar` ie.

```
foo(mybar::bar)
```

How can I test this function in `Groovy` elegantly?

Using:

```
mybar.&bar
```

yields a `groovy.lang.Closure<...>` which is not compatible with `java.util.function.Function`.

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: Try coercing to `Function`, like this: `foo(mybar.&bar as Function)`

Comment: @BalRog That seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: @balrog you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: In general I hesitate to post something as an answer unless I have tried it myself and verified that it works. In this case I just didn't have time to do that, so I added it as a comment about something to attempt. Since it *did* work I'll go ahead and post it as an answer after the fact.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Coerce the final attempt to `Function`, like this:

```
foo(mybar.&bar as Function)
```